# Convert CSV into Dictionary using python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a CSV/EXCEL file. The sample data is shown below

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
|  Number   | start_date |  end_date  |
+-----------+------------+------------+
| 987654321 | 2021-07-15 | 2021-08-15 |
| 999999999 | 2021-07-15 | 2021-08-15 |
| 888888888 | 2021-07-15 | 2021-08-15 |
| 777777777 | 2021-07-15 | 2021-09-15 |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

I need to convert it into a dictionary(JSON) with some condition on it and then pass that dictionary(JSON) into the DB rows. This means the CSV can provide n number of dictionaries.

Conditions to applied:

1. The numbers which are having the same start date and end date should be in the same dictionary.
2. All numbers in a dictionary should be concatenated with comma(,) string.

Expected dictionaries from the above input

```
dict1 = {
  "request": [
    {
      "key": "AMI_LIST",
      "value": "987654321,999999999,888888888"
    },
    {
      "key": "START_DATE",
      "value": "2021-07-15"
    },
    {
      "key": "END_DATE",
      "value": "2021-08-15"
    }
  ]
}

dict2 = {
  "request": [
    {
      "key": "AMI_LIST",
      "value": "7777777777"
    },
    {
      "key": "START_DATE",
      "value": "2021-07-15"
    },
    {
      "key": "END_DATE",
      "value": "2021-09-15"
    }
  ]
}
```

All these dictionaries will be stored as a model object and then will pass on to DB. I am not creating different variables for each dict it will handle in a loop. It is just a notation that I want to explain using variables dict1 and dict2.

**NOTE**: The maximum rows in a file will be 500 only.

I have tried using for loop but that will increase the complexity. Is there any other way to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried itreating the CSV/Excel file using for loop and then writing it into the dictionary. which decreases the performance of the function and the function also became a messed up which is hard to handle in case of any change required in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yep pandas is a really good option, you can do something like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv("table.csv")
dfgrp = df.groupby(['end_date', 'start_date'], as_index = False).agg({"Number": list})
dfgrp.to_json()
```

which gives you :

```
{
 'end_date': {'0': '2021-08-15', '1': '2021-09-15'},
 'start_date': {'0': '2021-07-15', '1': '2021-07-15'},
 'Number': {'0': [987654321, 999999999, 888888888], '1': [777777777]}
}
```

And you're almost there !

Answer (score 0):

how about using `pandas` to do the job?

it should be capable of reading your excel-files in as a DataFrame [(see here)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), then you can apply your conditions and use `DataFrame.to_json` [(see here)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) to export your DataFrames to json files